# MSVC bug? Template friend function cannot access private members despite template friend declaration

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-bug

I have the following C++ code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Foo;

template<typename T, typename U>
Foo<T> operator+(Foo<T> lhs, const Foo<U>& rhs);

template<typename T>
class Foo {
    template<typename>
    friend class Foo;

    T inner;

public:
    Foo(T i) : inner(i) {}

    template<typename U>
    friend Foo<T> operator+(Foo<T> lhs, const Foo<U>& rhs) {
        lhs.inner += rhs.inner;
        return lhs;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> a = 4;
    Foo<unsigned> b = 5;
    Foo<int> c = a + b;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9d1Krs4Yo)

It compiles fine with GCC and clang, but compilation fails with an error in MSVC v19.37 and in Visual Studio 2015:

```
example.cpp
<source>(19): error C2248: 'Foo<unsigned int>::inner': cannot access private member declared in class 'Foo<unsigned int>'
<source>(12): note: see declaration of 'Foo<unsigned int>::inner'
<source>(26): note: see declaration of 'Foo<unsigned int>'
<source>(27): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Foo<int> operator +<unsigned int>(Foo<int>,const Foo<unsigned int> &)' being compiled
<source>(27): note: see the first reference to 'operator +' in 'main'
Compiler returned: 2
```

This seems to be some kind of issue with MSVC. Is there a workaround? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like the workaround from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69578227/847382) also works with my issue: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kr3q6G3TY)

Comment: Suppose you should add the error message directly to the question...

Comment: The more I think about the more appears to me as if MSVS is actually right (oh, that's really rare…): If `T` and `U` differ we have two different, entirely unrelated classes `Foo<T>` and `Foo<U>` – each one defining a separate overload for `operator+` – and each one only making its own overload a friend! So now how should the overload of one Foo-instantiation access the inner members of the other one???

Comment: That's what `template<typename> friend class Foo` is for, right?

Comment: Solely that each `operator+`, due to the `friend` keyword, is **not** a member of the surrounding template class! So this friend declaration remains ineffective in that case.

Comment: Okay, it appears the best workaround is to create a private static template function with the implementation, then call that from the template friend function. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1qnjY3TeY)

Comment: [This variant](https://godbolt.org/z/5sEP1ds7s) does work – interestingly MSVC doesn't allow the template to be defined within the class (`function template has already been defined`), `inline` keyword doesn't help out either. Now this appears suspicious to me, here I'd rather assume MSVC not being right, but cannot put my hand in fire for.

Comment: It looks to me that neither of the three is right. It should compile even without `template<typename> friend class Foo;` because every specialization of `operator+` is a friend of (every specialization of) `Foo` (https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#4).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Well, the `friend class Foo` is ineffective anyway, no matter if any of the compilers is right or not, as none of these operators is a member of the surrounding class, as mentioned already ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Neither gcc nor clang accept this code if the "ineffective" friend is removed.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI This doesn't appear right to me either, appears to me as a bug in both of them if this `friend` makes them accept. And about *'every specialisation [being] friend'*: This would apply for every arbitrary `U` – but in given context `T` is already fixed, so that phrase wouldn't apply on it any more, the operator only can access the inner members of the respective `Foo<T>`.

Comment: @Aconcagua Hmm you are right. In the original version of the code different instantiations of `Foo` declare different unrelated `operator+` templates (and `operator+` template declared before `Foo` is yet another one, related to none of them). All of that in such an innocent looking piece of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to move the actual implementation into a static method, and call that static method inside the friend function:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    template<typename>
    friend class Foo;

    T inner;

    template<typename U>
    static Foo op_add(Foo lhs, const Foo<U>& rhs) {
        lhs.inner += rhs.inner;
        return lhs;
    }

public:
    Foo(T i) : inner(i) {}

    template<typename U>
    friend Foo operator+(Foo lhs, const Foo<U>& rhs) {
        return op_add(lhs, rhs);
    }
};
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EWG9oY1cc)

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your example code.

1. you are using `Foo` template parameter on `friend` function. This has impact on how compiler sees this declaration and confuses compiler (that is why for while I deleted first version of my answer). Friend function should not depend on `T`!
2. Defining function in place of where friendship is declared is buggy on all compilers even when generic programing is not in use. So I would recommend you to avoid this as a rule of thumb.

If you define function template with own template parameters and outside of scope `Foo` class template it works without nasty hacks.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    T inner;

public:
    Foo(T i) : inner(i) {}

    T get() const {
        return inner;
    }

    template<typename W, typename U>
    friend auto operator+(Foo<W> lhs, const Foo<U>& rhs) -> Foo<W>;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K8e3dKf4v

Note also I removed some noise code from your example.

Comment: That's now interesting... I would have assumed that the friend declaration should have comprised two template parameters `U` and `V`, independent from `T` – as in the link in my comment to the question. And if my reasoning there is correct this variant should have been rejected for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: @Aconcagua you are right.  After your comment under question I did some checking and noticed that compiler got completely consumed and didn't file an error (probably linker would). So I've edit my answer to cover your input - I do not know why you see old version of my answer.

Comment: Here is some experiment which I did: https://godbolt.org/z/hPErPE4Ph and I notice that compiler didn't optimize call of a `operator+` function. This was signal for me that linker would be confused as you can see it files an error.

Comment: Hmm... That appears actually correct to me: We have a template `operator+` accepting two template parameters – and each `Foo<T>` declares yet another overloaded template `operator+` – but with only one single template parameter. And there's no definition for.

Comment: Oh, and we don't get a compilation error for accessing private members in the two-template parameter variant because the one parameter overloads are a better match and thus the two parameter one is never instantiated.

Comment: And now getting into the dilemma, how can I define the one-template-parameter overload declared from within the template class??? What's the correct syntax for?

Comment: Just a side note: I'd rather remove the getter, it's actually irrelevant for the problem and we don't know either if the value maybe just represents a pure internal state...